# What is the use of alumium profile with LED strip lighting?

Tags: lighting, led, shed

I am thinking of installing LED strip lights into my shed. I have found that there is something called aluminium profile that can be installed where the LED strip goes on top of it or inside it.

Is the purpose of aluminium profile only to diffuse the LED light using a translucent surface or are there other purposes as well like changing angle of the LED strip? I am asking this since there are different type of aluminium profiles and I am not at all sure what their aim is.

Comment: I changed angle using wood (triangular 1m*1cm*0.5 cm profile) - this was cheaper and less cumbersome. Also, not all profiles include diffusors (or even options for them) - make sure to check twice before buying. If you have enough LEDs per meter or illuminate stuff far enough you might not need them.

Comment: so due to cost reason, a wooden profile at an angle would be preferred?

Comment: For ME, I believe it was the best option, yes. Cheap and small. I don't think it would be the best for everyone - say if you also need/want heatsink or diffusors or protection or ... (see answers) this wooden thingy doesn't help you much.

Comment: The aluminium profile may function as a heat sink as well. I have tri-colour LEDs that get very hot in use, the strip draws something like 40W per meter. The aluminium profile heat sink is required.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem - you don't want a led strip at all. LED strips are for decoration. They're ineffective at lightning, expensive per lumen and power inefficient. They're basically a permanent version of Christmas tree lights. They have no function to serve in a shed.

Comment: @Agent_L It depends on which LED strip product you choose.  LED strips are commonly used as under-cabinet lights, and the efficiency of such products is very near to A19 LED bulbs (110-120 lumens per watt). I wouldn't want to use them as work lights in a shed-based shop, but they'd be just fine in a storage shed.  They are *much* more expensive than a standard light fixture & bulb though.

Comment: Though "*much*" might be overstating it when we're talking about a project with less than $100 in materials regardless of whether you use standard fixtures or strips.

Comment: @TimSparkles I believe that's efficiency of the LED alone, which is pretty much bound to be same. But constant voltage LED strips are resistor-regulated, so it's not possible to match the efficiency of switch-mode regulation of integrated light units. Also, you have to subtract the ~80-90% efficiency of the 12V PSU you're using, which is already accounted for in integrated units. On top of that you get the shitty distribution profile of bare led, so not all your lumens go where you want them, yielding less lux. A decoration. (Under cabinet there's shadow so any light is a big improvement).

Comment: ok, so based on the information I have received, I shall not be using LED strips after all. This question has been most helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it mostly serves as a convenient way to mount the strips, and transfer money from you to the people who make and/or sell it.

Some versions do appear to have a diffuser as well as the mounting strip, but that's more than just an aluminum profile, it's one *with a diffuser strip.* Some serve to alter the angle of the strip light. All serve as a thing that the strip light slides or pops into.

These differences from a plain mounting channel appear to be obvious, to me - if it has a diffuser, then part of its function is to diffuse. (That's not free, by the way - you lose some light going through the diffuser.)

If it mounts the strip at an angle from the surface, then angling it is part of its purpose.

If it does neither, it's just a mount.

Comment: Confirming with an actual case. We used one for over the kitchen bench, under the cupboards.   It makes it look tidy as it's visible and for the same reason the diffuser makes it look more like a strip than discrete LEDs.

Comment: +1 for opening paragraph - they've got to sell you something to differentiate their 100m LEDs on a roll from the other otherwise identical 100m LEDs on a roll ;)

Comment: -1 Why so negative? If someone wants a clean-looking light strip with very easy mounting, then this is the way to go. It's a feature, not an evil money grab. If the aluminium were optional, they would leave it off (or go out of business as everyone would just buy LEDs on a strip).

Comment: LED strip glued to ceiling directly will usually fall off pretty quickly, unless you do a really good job with cleaning the surface. So yeah, a lot more convenient to glue the strip inside a profile and screw the profile in place.

Comment: Recommended, @jpa, to screw the profile in place _then_ glue the lights in. Otherwise, you tend to run the screws through all the delicate wiring, ruining the strip. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Heh, yeah, if the profile is one where the only mounting holes are under the strip. But those are annoying to reposition, so I would avoid them.

Comment: @jpa If it's the kind where the light strip slides in from the end they're not so bad. No adhesive to worry about at all.

Comment: High power leds have a warning "do not run without a heatsink". So that's a very important purpose aluminium serves. People tend to think that "leds are cool so heat is not a problem", while leds actually create heat problems and require complicated cooling.

Comment: @AnoE is mentioning that products are made to get you to buy them somehow inherently negative?

Answer (score 19):

- They provide physical support, e.g. when mounting a strip across several rafters.
- They provide some physical protection, e.g. against swinging
  garden implements.
- Some provide protection against moisture, but they must be carefully sealed at wire entries and the like.
- They provide a heat sink. High power strips, e.g. with four rows of LEDs, may require a heat sink.

Comment: What is "swinging garden implements"?

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 Not sure what your shed is for, but if it is used for scythes (The classic swinging garden implement!), rakes, pole pruners and other outdoor tools then there is a fair chance that one of them will hit a light while being casually handled. If it's a workshop then lumber may be the predominant hazard. Potting wheels shouldn't be much of a problem, nor large televisions.

Comment: Re: Physical support - an aluminum channel is the difference between a clean straight line and a slightly wobbly line. Diffusers on top of the aluminum channel are the difference between a clean, solid line and a dotted line.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 Garden implements that swing.

Answer (score 6):

Listen to [HABO's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/266325/103738) and [the one from Ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/266313/103738), but there are some things to add. I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so my advice comes as an answer:

1. Adhesion: Most LED stripes have poor glue strips and will curl up and away from the surface they are glued on. This is especially true for grainy surfaces like wood. Aluminium profiles can be screwed and offer good contact, some even allow you to slide stripes in from the side, mitigating the whole problem. This will also help exchange the stripe when a few modules start to fail
2. Diffusion: You probably think that open strips will be fine, but that is rarely the case. Diffusors make a world of difference because they turn blindingly bright dots into soft bars of light (when viewed directly). Making one yourself is possible, but takes a lot more work than using premade diffusion strips. An alternative is to use indirect light by shining on an adjacent surface.
3. Straight lines are hard to to when gluing by hand, profiles help
4. Expect the stripe to get warm, heatsinking LEDs will prolong their life. This can be fine when running a low brightness, but that's rarely the case for working lights in sheds.

Comment: Just a note regarding diffusion - do not assume you need diffusor just because the led strip itself has many bright spots. At few meters light may be completely uniform so diffusor would only throw some light away for no gain. But if your LED strip is illuminating something close or you actually look at it often, you indeed want something uniform.